# Phonegap Android app crashes after file selection from gallery

Tags: android, html, file-upload, cordova

I am having a requirement of using basic **HTML5** input type="file" tag to select and upload file from gallery but when i try to select a file(e.g. small image) the app crashes and shows this message --->

```
Unfortunately,the process com.example.app.mobile**(activity package) has stopped
```

Please find below the logs also

```
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=5173, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/audio/media/1166 }} to activity {com.example.app.mobile/com.example.app.mobile.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3141)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3184)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.onActivityResult(DroidGap.java:829)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3137)
02-25 17:17:21.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: how abt using phonegap filetransfer

Comment: Hi Divesh,I had tried phonegap filetransfer also still the same issue,I think its the issue with the mainactivity java file

Comment: can anyone please help me out to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may happen due to permission to read users file on device.
Add following lines on your platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`